# What is this device strapped around the nut of an electric guitar?

Tags: guitar

What is this device strapped around the nut of the guitar in this image?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a string damper - it stops open strings ringing. This can be very useful for a range of playing styles.

I tend to use a handkerchief tucked under the strings for some Satriani-style tapping melodies, as it allows me to use two hands at speed up the neck of the guitar without having to damp every note.

Comment: May I extend this saying the damper is used heavily when sweep picking as it mutes out the previous strings, stopping them ringing out.

Comment: Interesting. I'm trying to perfect my sweep picking and hadn't thought of this.

Comment: Mark J. Smith uses a plain old black sock in his [bass tapping lessons](http://www.talkingbass.net/tapping-bass-guitar-lesson-part-1/), which looks hilarious around the end of his slick Ibanez bass.